# Android: GC_CONCURRENT freed

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Every application I create using android studio runs slow and some unbearably slow. I dont know why this is and it did not used to happen. I dont have any clue how to fix this.

This is my log if it helps:
[image]

Is this something to dow this Garbarg collection?

Comment: you talking about real devices or in the emulator?

Comment: just in emulation

Comment: android emulator is not famous for its speed. It also might be (from your logcat I infer) that OpenGL is running on emulation mode. Try to configure native opengl for the emulation (google it), or try on a real device or in Ganymotion emulator. The GC issue is not relevant here.

Comment: it also mentions something about main thread to much work?